# Unexpected top-level exception after changing package name

Tags: java, android, android-studio, package, parseexception

I am working on an Android Studio project and ran into a problem when I tried to create a package that started with a capital letter (I forgot what it was at this point, but that's not the issue at hand). So I changed the package name from `Adapters` to `adapters` and now I can no longer compile.

I receive the following error message:

> com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name
>   (com/example/android/myAppName/adapters/AccountAdapter$ViewHolder)
>   does not match path
>   (com/example/android/myAppName/Adapters/AccountAdapter$ViewHolder.class)

How can I change it so that it no longer tries to match the path with the capital A?

Comment: Tried "Clean Project"?

Comment: @dannyroa oh my god I feel like the dumbest programmer in the world right now. I'm up and running again, that fixed the issue.

Comment: @dannyroa any idea what causes that though? Is it a bug in Android Studio, since the refactoring of the package name didn't work?

Comment: It's not a bug. The Build Tool doesn't recognize the package name change and reuses the cache. "Clean Project" forces to rebuild all the classes.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much for the insight.

Comment: No problem. "Clean Project" is a solution to most Build errors! :)

Answer (score 4):

This issue has been resolved. Thanks to aid of a commenter, I no longer received this exception after running "Clean Project" in Android Studio.

See the comments to the question for more explanation on why this happened.

Comment: same to me, renamed package and got this error, clean project halped