# Android Studio fails to Build after package name refactor

Tags: android, android-studio

I forked one of my old projects, so I refactored the package name in the Android manifest XML. The actual package name and all the references in JAVA are renamed properly. However, when I run I get the following error message:

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class
{my.old.package/my.new.package.gui.activities.LightSettingsActivity} 
does not exist.
```

Apparently, the old package name is somewhere in configuration files where it does not belong I think.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Why not just create a new project and name it appropriately then just copy your classes and res files?

Comment: please share your manifest file.

Answer (score 6):

I have had a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537269/unexpected-top-level-exception-after-changing-package-name) issue. If you go to Build -> Clean Project, everything should work for you.

To quote a comment on my question:

> It's not a bug. The Build Tool doesn't recognize the package name
>   change and reuses the cache. "Clean Project" forces to rebuild all the
>   classes

Comment: The Clean project build does not seem to run properly, so I think your answer is on the right track.

Comment: Triple check the spelling anywhere that package name was used, and maybe use copy/paste if you have to to ensure they're all the same. If you're positive you've made no spelling errors and the clean project still fails, let me know what error you're getting from the clean. @user1111652

Comment: I checked after cleaning project.....somehow it didn't work then I tried system restart and fortunately it worked!!
Please check and respond :-)

Answer (score 3):

After refactoring, you need to manually change the value of `applicationId` in the app-level `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

1. Rename the package through Android Studio's refactor feature.
2. Clean the project and rebuild it.
3. If Android Studio still cannot launch the app, go to the shell, navigate to your project directory and do:

   `$ find . -type f -exec grep -Hi "nameofoldpackage" "{}" ";"`

   If you find the name in one of your source files, change these occurrences as well.

   If the package is found in the build or .gradle directory, Android Studio seems to have failed to clean the project properly. Close Android Studio, then do:

   `$ cd /path/to/project
   $ rm -rf .gradle/
   $ rm -rf build/`

   Reopen Android Studio and rebuild.
4. If you still can't launch the app, the most likely cause is that you did not specify an `applicationId` in your build.gradle. Open the build.gradle file and add the appropriate `applicationId`. For instructions, see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html

Answer (score 2):

I am using Android studio 4.1.2 and I found a bug there. If you are passing a Serializable/Parcelable object in nav_graph as safeargs and then rename the class/package name of the class, Android Studio doesn't change the package name in nav_graph. you have to manually change the package name there and try to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android Studio, it's recommended that you refactor the name by clicking right on your project --> refactor --> rename because the IDE will change the name of the project in all files (including the class R that you "can't" edit) then clean & build your project

Answer (score 0):

in my case just resync wih gradle and rebuild the project helped me out.

so:
1- Clean project
2- invalidate cache/restart from file menu
3- resync wih gradle

wish this make it easy and help.

Answer (score 0):

I did everything in these answers and in all other locations, no use, Do this:

1. Stop refactoring/renaming package names,and there are some dependencies you may not be able to change if you are new to Android Development, which is why I think you have asked the question in the first place.
2. Exit Android Studio
3. Copy all your files to a new folder.
4. Go to the "\app\src\main\java\com" folder, then change the folder at the top, and the subfolder to your liking.
5. Open this project with Android Studio now, just build and get away with it.

If you really want to change everything inside your project,
Create a new package under com package, name it whatever you want, then move the sub-package that's under the oldpackage to new package, and let android studio do the heavy lifting. Follow the same for the package inside sub-package.